# Form element style incorrect only when inside an unstyled HTML Details tag

Tags: css, html, bulma

A sample form control taken from the Bulma CSS framework documentation works as expected using Bulma 0.7.2 (latest at time of writing).

However, when the form is put inside a standard html `<details>` tag, the height of the element changes, and some width (of the input?) changes, so that there's a visual glitch when hovering over the input.

What's causing this, and is there a style that can be applied to the `<details>` tag that would make the form element display correctly?

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bulma/0.7.2/css/bulma.css">

<div class="field has-addons">
  <div class="control">
    <input class="input" type="text" placeholder="Find a repository">
  </div>
  <div class="control">
    <a class="button is-info">
      Search
    </a>
  </div>
</div>

<br>
<br>

<details>
  <div class="field has-addons">
  <div class="control">
    <input class="input" type="text" placeholder="Find a repository">
  </div>
  <div class="control">
    <a class="button is-info">
      Search
    </a>
  </div>
</div>
</details>
```

Edit: as a more minimal example, the style is also wrong for a single `<input class="input" type="text" placeholder="Find a repository">` element inside the `<details>` tag.

Answer (score 1):

The reason this is happening is because the padding in the input and the button is calculated based on em's and since the input is inside a `<details>` tag, it must be interfering with the proportions somehow - See image below:

[image]

I'm not familiar with this framework, I'm not sure there would be a way to adjust the issue. In any case, the quickest workaround would be to target the input and button inside the `<details>` tag and add a static padding-top and padding-bottom of 0 to both the button and the input inside the `<details>` tag:

```
details .input,
details .button{
  padding-bottom: 0;
  padding-top: 0;
}
```

After that, I find that if you reduce the input max-width to 89% instead of 100% it amends the issue with the hovering:

```
details .input{
  max-width: 89%;
}
```

Comment: Thanks! This is very helpful. Can't quite replicate the max-width behavior though, it seems to only work sometimes.